# Install conda package locally from other local environment

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda

I have a conda package which is no longer available anywhere online installed in a virtual environment. How can I install this package into a new virtual environment? Ideally I would also like to archive this package somewhere as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the package cache (i.e., in `conda config --show pkgs_dirs`), then you can install it with `conda install --offline pkg_name`. Also check if the tarball is still downloaded - that would be a natural archive, and one can directly install from a tarball (e.g., `conda install path/to/pkg_name.tar.bz2`).